# How to add multiple values ​to a dictionary key

Tags: python

Okay, I'm going to edit my question.

I am trying to store in a .json file, the prices of products with the corresponding date.

I get the data from another .json file with various products, which are updated every day.

```
cache_file = get_cache(cache_file)
```

cache_file is a list with dictionaries, and in each dictionary there is a product with its details.

```
[{"title": "Product 1", "price": 11695000, "img": "img-link", 
"link": "link-to-product", "estado_precio": "="}, {"title": "Product 2", 
"price": 8925000, "img": "img-link", "link": "link-to-product", 
"estado_precio": "="}, {"title": "Product 3", "price": 8200000, "img": "img- 
link", "link": "link-to-product", "estado_precio": "="}]
```

Then I get the details of each product, where I want to store the price in another .json file with the current date.

```
product_prices_date = defaultdict(list)
for products_details in cache_file:                       
    prices_date = {}
    prices_date[fecha] = products_details['price']     
    product_prices_date[products_details['title']].append(prices_date)
            
save_to_cache(product_prices_date, cache_file)
```

The code stores correctly, but every day it overwrites the results

```
{"Product 1": [{"12-09-2020": 1169}], "Product 2": [{"12-09-2020": 8925}], "Product 3": [{"12-09-2020": 820}]}
```

What I need is to store the prices and dates without overwriting

something like this:

```
{"Product 1": [{"12-09-2020": 1169}, {"13-09-2020": 1269}], "Product 2": [{"12-09-2020": 8925}, {"13-09-2020": 8925}], "Product 3": [{"12-09-2020": 820}, {"13-09-2020": 850}]}
```

Would you help me to obtain the result I seek?
Regards

Comment: It would really help if you provided a [mre]. Your code isn't indented properly, and your input data is missing. You can [edit] the question. BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want more advice.

Comment: why would you expect any different?  you reinitialize product_prices_date to empty each time and write to it from scratch.  save and load it from somewhere and maybe your code will work.  something like `product_prices_date = load_cache(cache_file)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @SauravPathak says, you want to read in the JSON file from the previous run to reconstruct your data structure in memory, add the current set of data to that, and then save the data structure back out to the file.  Here's roughly the code you'd need to do that:

```
import json
import os

output_path = '/tmp/report.json'

def add_daily_vaules(file):

    # Read in existing data file if it exists, else start from empty dict
    if os.path.exists(output_path):
        with open(output_path) as f:
            product_prices_date = json.load(f)
    else:
        product_prices_date = {}

    # Add each of today's products to the data
    for products_details in file:
        title = products_details['title']
        price = products_details['price']
        date = products_details['date']
        # This is the key - you want to append to a prior entry for a specific
        # title if it already exists in the data, else you want to first add
        # an empty list to the data so that you can append either way
        if title in product_prices_date:
            prices_date = product_prices_date[title]
        else:
            prices_date = []
            product_prices_date[title] = prices_date
        prices_date.append({date:price})

    # Save the structure out to the JSON file
    with open(output_path, "w") as f:
        json.dump(f, product_prices_date)
```

Comment: Ok, I was able to get the result I was looking for with this code. I am very new to Python, and I am learning every day.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to read from json file first, parse it, then append to the parsed dict. And save to json file again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
product_prices_date = defaultdict(dict)
for products_details in file:  
                              
    product_prices_date[product_name].update({todays_date: products_details['price']})
            
save_to_cache(product_prices_date, cache_file)
```

So your result will be stored in this manner

```
{"Product 1": {"12-09-2020": 1169, "13-09-2020": 1269}, ..}
```

and you can fetch price of product of a particular date like below

```
product_prices_date[product_name][date]
```

Comment: This gives me the same result, it keeps overwriting.

Comment: If you notice, in the first line, I have added `defaultdict(dict)` and if its overwriting, you may multiple values for same date

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to simulate your code (see below). And everything is ok with it. Probably something wrong with a file you are reading from or with a method how you process your source data.

```
from collections import defaultdict
product_prices_date = defaultdict(list)
prices_date = {}
prices_date = {1:2}
product_prices_date['p1'].append(prices_date)
prices_date = {}
prices_date = {1:3}
product_prices_date['p1'].append(prices_date)
prices_date = {}
prices_date = {1:2}
product_prices_date['p2'].append(prices_date)
prices_date = {}
prices_date = {1:3}
product_prices_date['p2'].append(prices_date)
print(product_prices_date)
```

Result:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'p1': [{1: 2}, {1: 3}], 'p2': [{1: 2}, {1: 3}]})
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Please give examples posting a code is not simple enough, the op would not have a clue what to do with your code.